# HttpURLConnection error

Tags: android, url, connect, httpurlconnection, http-get

I want to get the HTML from a website, for that I'm using [this](http://pastebin.com/V6JnjZJp) code.
When I try to add [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) code from the documentation I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4UDw.png):

```
            //Get HTML
            URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                readStream(in);
                finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
```

What went wrong? Did I forget to import some stuff?

Comment: what do the errors say when you hover over them?

Comment: On the first one: "Unhandled exception: java.net.MalformedURLException". The 2th en 3th one: "Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't forget to import anything.

There's a couple things wrong with the code.

1) You're missing the catch block to go along with try and your `finally` statement is incorrectly inside the if. It should look like the follow:

```
try {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);
} catch (Exception e) { // best practice is to be more specific with the Exception type
    urlConnection.disconnect();
    Log.w("Login", "Error downloading HTML from " + url);        
} finally {
    if(urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

2) In that example you are following in the documentation, they are leaving it up to you to decide what to do with the stream once it it retrieved from the `urlConnection`.

So create your own `void readStream(InputStream in)` method in your activity which can then consume the InputStream. Write it to disk, display it on screen, its up to you.

Comment: And if I want the result to a String, I can use: String example = urlConnection.toString();

Comment: Because I want to print to a EditText field.

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string will help you getting your inputstream into a stream.

Comment: This answer specifically will help you, without needing external libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10505933/798464

Comment: I use this code with an onClicklistener now, only still it isnt working. Nothing shows up in my EditText field.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `catch` clause. Put this before your `finally` clause as such:

```
} catch (Exception e) { //it's bad practice to catch Exception, specify it more if you can, i just don't know what errors InputStream throws
    Log.e("ClassTag", e.getMessage(), e);
} finally { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: My bad. Didn't know that, now I do.

Answer (score 0):

The finally block does not go inside the try block, change it to:

```
 try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
 }
 finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Also make sure that you have imported `java.net.URL`.